# How to get strings first 4 characters after first semicolon

Tags: c#, string

I have a string and my requirement is that from my string I should get the first 4 characters from first semicolon(;).

I have below code:

```
var str1 = Settings.Default.sConstr.ToString();
var str2 = Settings.Default.dConstr.ToString();
string name = //sub string of str1 + sub string of str2;
```

How can we do this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Split()` to do this.

```
var str1 = Settings.Default.sConstr.Split(';');
var str2 = Settings.Default.dConstr.Split(';');
string name = str1[1].Substring(0,4)+" "+str2[1].Substring(0,4);
```

Hope it work.

Comment: I added exception handling for your answer, which is important for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "asdfghj;zxcvb";
var index = s.IndexOf(';');
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(index -4, 4));
```

Output will be;

```
fghj
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/PELlq1)</kbd>.

If you looking 4 character **AFTER** semi column, you can use it like;

```
string s = "asdfghj;zxcvb";
var index = s.IndexOf(';');
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(index + 1, 4));
```

Output will be;

```
zxcv
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/EAXwhz)</kbd>.

Also checking your string contains `;` character and it has 4 character after `;` is a good ideas like;

```
if(s.Contains(';') && (s.Length >= s.IndexOf(';') + 5))
{
 //Your code
}
```

Comment: I think that "first 4 characters" mean first 4 characters AFTER the first semicolon.

Comment: @GrantWinney and Konrad Gadzina, you can be right guys. Updated my answer. Thanks for warning.

Comment: A program like this cannot trust on the input, you have to make sure the input contains a semi-colon and the next characters are >= 4 characters...

Comment: @glautrou You have a point. Updated as your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf(';'), 4) + str2.Substring(str2.IndexOf(';'), 4);
```

or if you want `4` `chars` after the `;` then use this one:

```
str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf(';') + 1, 4) + str2.Substring(str2.IndexOf(';') + 1, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var stringToGetFrom = "some characters;Get this stuff.";
var chars = stringToGetFrom.SkipWhile(c => c != ';').Skip(1).Take(3);

// Will contain the string "Get":
var selectedString = new string(chars.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "asdfghj;zxcvb";
string result = s.Split(new char[]{';'})[1].Substring(0,4);
```

or:

```
string s = "asdfghj;zxcvb";
var chars = s.Split(new char[] { ';' })[1].ToCharArray().Take(4).ToArray();
string result = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 sConstr.Split(';')[1].Substring(0,4)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/CqANkC)